# Gitlab CI replace appearence in files

Tags: regex, gitlab

We sometimes struggle with updating CSS / JS files for our customers when they're cached. A common hack we found is to append an version tag to the  in our sourcecode (style.min.css becomes style.min.css?v=123 for example).

We wanted to integrate that change in our Gitlab CI/CD pipelines that we already use to sync the repository with our FTP server where the websites are hosted.

I came up with the following script (note: we're using the docker:latest image)

```
stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add lftp

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sed -i -E 's/(\.css\?|\.css\")/\.css?v='$CI_JOB_ID'\&\"/g' templates/index.php
    - sed -i -E 's/(\.js\?|\.js\")/\.js?v='$CI_JOB_ID'\&\"/g' templates/index.php
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS $FTP_HOST; mirror -Rv ./ ./gitlab-ci-test --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  only:
    - master
```

That's working fine, except when we use css/js files that already have an ?something=something in their reference. I want to keep that, but how...

style.min.css should become style.min.css?v=ID (this is working already with the file I have included above)

style.min.css?x=y should become style.min.css?v=ID&x=y

Can somebody help me out or come up with a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

First handle the case `style.min.css?x=y`:

```
s/\.css\?/.css?v='$CI_JOB_ID'&/g
```

Then handle the case `style.min.css`:

```
s/\.css([^?])/.css?v='$CI_JOB_ID'$1/g
```